# Does APNdroid eat battery?

Tags: battery-life, data-connection, apn

Someone suggested that APNdroid will cause your battery to drain because your phone is continually attempting to connect to the disabled APN. Makes sense, but I wonder if there's something I'm missing? Does APNdroid burn battery any faster than having a good APN and using data?

Comment: Good question. I would think (but do not know) that using data would consume more battery than searching (and not finding) a network to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm it will attempt to connect all the time and drain battery in half a day in my case. To solve it you should untick the data in the network settings and check that GPRS/EDGE/HSPDA icon is not visible on top next to the signal strength bars. But at least APNdroid (or manually modify the APN name) will prevent any connection and any extra charge during roaming session.

Comment: Thankfully, my new Galaxy S has a "Data Network Mode" setting I can turn off.